# How to Create Separate environment for AWS SNS SMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

I want to create separate Environments for sending SMS using Amazon SNS services.
for example, every project has 3 envs Dev, test & prod. So I want to create a separate environment for all three

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to create a topic and three subscriptions, one per environment. Then, use message attributes when publishing to the topic and message filtering in the subscriptions.

For example, when you want to push something for dev, you would push the message to the topic using the `dev` message attribute. On the other side, all of the subscriptions attached to the topic with filtering enabled to receive only `dev` messages will receive that message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use SNS Topics for this.

1. Create 3 Topics per project: Dev, Test and Prod
2. Subscribe your recipients' numbers to respective topics
3. Your system environment can then choose which topic to send to, probably based on the environment variables that you configure. The message will be broadcast to all numbers subscribed to the topic.

Ref:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-topic.html

Comment: I need to subscribe numbers then able to send sms